# cassandra : datastax LocalDate Type mismatch to java.util.Date # scala Akka

Tags: scala, date, cassandra, akka, datastax

I have been struggling to rectify this type mismatch issue.i am getting resultset record from cassandra. the query used is :

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
  key text PRIMARY KEY,
  user_user varchar,
  text text,
  createdat timestamp
  ) WITH comment='Tweets'
    AND COMPACT STORAGE
    AND read_repair_chance = 1.0;
```

cqlsh:akkacassandra> `select * from tweets;`

```
 key | createdat | text | user_user
-----+-----------+------+-----------

(0 rows)
cqlsh:akkacassandra>
```

this is the code blocks where the types are defined:

some part in **Tweet.scala**

```
case class Tweet(id: TweetId, user: User, text: Text, createdAt: Date)
```

Some portion in **tweetread.scala**

```
def buildTweet(r: Row): Tweet = {
    val id = r.getString("key")
    val user = r.getString("user_user")
    val text = r.getString("text")
    val createdAt = r.getDate("createdat")
    Tweet(id, user, text, createdAt)
  }
```

but i am getting the below erros while running using sbt.

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Akka Actors\activator-akka-cassandra-master\project
[info] Set current project to activator-akka-cassandra (in build file:/C:/Akka%20Actors/activator-akka-cassandra-master/)
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to C:\Akka Actors\activator-akka-cassandra-master\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\Akka Actors\activator-akka-cassandra-master\src\main\scala\core\tweetread.scala:29: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate
[error]  required: java.util.Date
[error]     Tweet(id, user, text, createdAt)
[error]                           ^
```

I have tried some solutions like wrapping the `r.getDate("createdat")` with `java.util.Date objec`t.But no luck.Any suggestions are appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getTimestamp`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/GettableByNameData.html#getTimestamp-java.lang.String-), which returns a `java.util.Date`:

```
def buildTweet(r: Row): Tweet = {
  val id = r.getString("key")
  val user = r.getString("user_user")
  val text = r.getString("text")
  val createdAt = r.getTimestamp("createdat") // <---
  Tweet(id, user, text, createdAt)
}
```